# how to put button and text in the same line?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to put icon, "Notification" and  in the same line, but  appears in the new line.

```
    <button (click)="openPage()">
      <icon name="notifications"></icon> Notification <h1>New</h1>
    </button>
```

Thanks

Comment: try like this: <button (click)="openPage()">
      <icon name="notifications"></icon> Notification <b>New</b>
    </button>

Comment: By default the H1 creates a new line. If still you want to use H1 than you can override default behavior using CSS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

by default `h1` is block element so it takes whole width of screen. You should use inline element like `span`. Here is the example for span

```html
<button (click)="openPage()">
      <icon name="notifications"></icon> Notification <span>New</span>
</button>
```

if you still want to use `h1`, use css to make it inline element

```css
#notification {
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<button (click)="openPage()">
      <icon name="notifications"></icon> Notification <h1 id="notification">New</h1>
</button>
```

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you create a CSS file and type `display: inline` as shown below.

CSS:

```
.inline {
    display: inline;
}
```

HTML:

```
<button class="inline" (click)="openPage()">
    <Icon and Text placed here></>
</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Give those elements' style: `display: inline-block` or `display: inline`